# Moving some Objects from Ax 2012 to Dynamics 365

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, dynamics-ax7, dynamics-ax-xpo

How do I **move** a project (an XPO file), (tables, forms) **from Ax 2012 R3 to Dynamics 365?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to convert an .xpo file into something that could be used in D365fO.

If you only want to move a few small objects, my suggestion would be to just reimplement them in D365fO.

Otherwise you should take a look at the Code Upgrade process, basically you want to move your objects to a new model, install that model on a clean AX 2012 R3 system, then upload the modelstore of that system to the LCS code upgrade service. More details in the following links:

- [Configure the code upgrade service in Lifecycle Services](https://ax.help.dynamics.com/en/wiki/configure-and-execute-the-code-upgrade-tile-in-lifecycle-services/)
- [The “Dynamics 365 for Operations” Code Upgrade Journey from Dynamics AX 2012](http://bluefort.com.mt/dynamics-365-for-operations-code-upgrade-steps-from-dynamics-ax-2012/)